# Need Immediate Roaming Profile / Folder Redirection file save with RDS Farm Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, folder-redirection, profile

I have roaming profiles set up with additional folder redirection deployed by GPO in a 2008 R2 RDS farm environment.

They are working well, but files added to folder locations in the profile (such as saving a file to the desktop) only replicate to the redirected location at logout.

Is there any way I can set this up so files are immediatley saved to the network location while the user is working prior to logout? My concern is that in the event of a server crash a user could lose hours of working data.

Thanks in advance, any relevant info one way or the other will get a vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. Have your users save their files to the redirected folders, such as My Documents, rather than saving to a folder in the roaming profile, such as the desktop.
2. Redirect their desktop folder.

Comment: I did redirect the desktop, and I see the redirected folder structure but the changes are still only committed at logoff. I take it that something is wrong?

Comment: @Az. if redirection setup is configured correctly, then all reads and writes will go directly to the new location.

Answer (score 1):

I have just been reading up on this too and found this:

◦By default, roaming user profiles are saved to the server only at logoff. Thus, to ensure that changes to the user profile are saved back to the server (if, for example, the user does not frequently log off) it is recommended that you enable the following Group Policy which is new in WS08 R2: 
Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> User Profiles -> Background upload of a roaming user profile’s registry file while user is logged on

Hope this helps